# How to use checkpoints in azure Kubernetes for spark submit

Tags: azure, apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-submit

How to configure spark job checkpoint in azure blob storage?

I was able to add checkpoints in Databricks but not in azure Kubernetes cluster
Can you please help me to overcome the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Spark `Checkpointing`:

> Checkpointing can be enabled by setting a directory in a
> fault-tolerant, reliable file system (e.g., HDFS, S3, etc.) to which
> the checkpoint information will be saved. This is done by using
> streamingContext.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory).

From
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing

This should be implemented in your code following the language you use using `StreamingContext.getOrCreate` which gets StreamingContext from checkpoint data or create a new one.